# Read a TIFF image in C# using libtiff.NET

Tags: c#, libtiff.net

I have a 16 bit grayscale tiff image that I need to read in C#. For that purpose, I use the libtiff.NET library. I tried to follow [official tutorials](http://bitmiracle.github.io/libtiff.net/html/c0ab407e-de25-46db-9cc9-e0bf3f1bc83d.htm) which demonstrate how to read colored images. However, the code in the tutorial fails with a `ObjectDisposedException`, I guess becuase my image is grayscale and not colored.

What I need in the end is a simple two-dimensional array that contains the pixel values of each pixel (ranging from 0 to 511). To get around the Exception, I tried libtiff's scanline based approach:

```
// read the height data
float[,] heightData = new float[dgm.NumberOfPixelsInX, dgm.NumberOfPixelsInZ];

// Read the image into the memory buffer 
int scanlineSize = dgm.ImageData.ScanlineSize();
byte[][] buffer = new byte[dgm.NumberOfPixelsInZ][];

for (int i = 0; i < dgm.NumberOfPixelsInZ; i++)
{
    buffer[i] = new byte[scanlineSize];
    dgm.ImageData.ReadScanline(buffer[i], i);
}

for (int x = 0; x < dgm.NumberOfPixelsInX; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < dgm.NumberOfPixelsInZ; y++)
    {
        heightData[x, y] = BitConverter.ToSingle(putBufferHere, 0);
    }
}
```

I know that `putBufferHere` needs to be something like `buffer[y]` but I am not entirely sure. As far as I understood it, one line in the buffer array contains the data for the entire row, so how do I get the data of one particular pixel?

Comment: How is the dgm object created? Is it inside a using? If so, the code you posted here should also be inside this using.

Comment: `dgm` is the instance of a wrapper class that contains libtiff's `Tiff`-object (`dgm.ImageData`) and some other metadata about the file. The `dgm` object comes from an index that is created at application startup (thus not created in a `using`)